# $_POST is showing in Chrome, but not being detected by PHP

Tags: php, post

I have a form that submits data to another page, which usually works, however sometimes I get this problem:

When I submit the form it shows up correctly in the 'Network' tab on the developer panel; however if I do `print_r($_POST)` it returns an empty array. This definitely is not a problem with my code, as Chrome is clearly picking up the `$_POST` data.

What can I do to solve this issue? It has only occurred a few times, however I do not want my users to experience this problem.

Comment: You really need to post your code here.  How is anyone supposed to answer what you are asking ?

Comment: Maybe you don't understand this but PHP is a server side language.  Anything problem you are experiencing definitely **is** a problem with your code and not browser related.  Unless you think you found a bug in PHP ;-)

Comment: I think you have misunderstood me, this cannot be a bug with my code. As I have shown, the `$_POST` request is sent, and I am merely using `print_r($_POST)` to view the data. There is no code that needs to be shown.

Comment: I just resubmitted the form then with the EXACT same code, and it worked. Like I said this isn't a fault on my hand, it must be a bug with PHP.

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with which browser you are using ,`$_POST` gets populated in `PHP` only when a form is submitted  using method as `post`.

Example

**form.html**

```
<form action="input.php" method="post">
    Input Your name:<input type="text" name="name">
    <input type="submit" value="post">
</form>
```

**input.php**

```
<?php
print_r($_POST);
?>
```

Now if you will visit form.html input your name and click post button a post request will be made and $_POST variable will get populated with the value you or your user enters and the above will look like:

```
Array
(
    [0] => jhon
)
```

but if you directly visit *input.php* the request method will be of type `get` and not post and `$_GET` veriable will get populated if there exist any values passed in url.

I hope this clears your concept.